# heroku cleardb client missing error

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, knex.js, cleardb

I am trying to migrate mysql database into heroku cleardb. I'm doing node service.
My tried code is,
**knexfile.js**

```
production: {
client: "mysql",
connection: {
  host:     "us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net",
  user:     "bcf521a*******",
  password: "9282****",
  database: "heroku_9c9d767dbb*****"
}    
}
```

in heroku, set the config with CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL.it done. When I try to run

```
heroku run node_modules/.bin/knex migrate:latest
Running node_modules/.bin/knex migrate:latest on ⬢ hidden-taiga-65640
... up, run.7007 (Free)
Using environment: production
```

The terminal error shows,

```
knex: Required configuration option 'client' is missing
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have NODE_ENV=production set in heroku environment? Also you didnt show the whole knex file so there might ve some problems too.

Comment: @MikaelLepistö, when I run the migration, it takes the env as production.

Comment: I try to import manually, that gives the current_timestamp error. coz of version

Answer (score 0):

Take a good, hard look at your env variables. Make sure that these match your variables in the Heroku app settings. Also, on your knexfile, make sure you're not using || to declare your environment:

```
const environment = process.env.ENV || 'development';
```

just leave the process.env.ENV.